# Thinkpad T14 Doesn't Wake Up From Suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, thinkpad, bios

I have a brand new Thinkpad T14 Gen 1 (type 20S0). When I let my computer go to sleep/suspend (close the lid) it sometimes is able to wake up again -- about 60% of the time; otherwise, it gets stuck in sleep mode (black screen and is unresponsive no matter what button I press), and I'm forced to shutdown and reboot. I haven't been able to figure out why it wakes up only some of the times.

I've tried:

- updating the BIOS
- increasing swap file size
- switching to newer/older kernel version
- installing, reinstalling various Linux distros, including newer/older Ubuntu versions
- GRUB_CMD_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0" in grub config*
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1" in grub config*

*I have Intel UHD Graphics, so it's not a graphics card issue (but I tried anyway) and there aren't any display drivers to install for Intel.

When I check the end of the previous boot's log, I fail to see any red flags:

```
Oct 10 01:10:28 mycomputer dbus-daemon[1574]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Ses>
Oct 10 01:10:28 mycomputer systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Oct 10 01:10:28 mycomputer systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Oct 10 01:10:28 mycomputer systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Oct 10 01:10:28 mycomputer systemd-sleep[247759]: Suspending system...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

not sure whether this is still relevant or not.

I had the same exact issue with Ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkPad T14 Gen 1 AMD.

My solution was to change the "Sleep Mode" option in the BIOS from "Windows 10" to "Linux"