# Thinkpad on Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't wake up from suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend, lenovo, amd-graphics, thinkpad

I have a new Lenovo Thinkpad P16s with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Any time I close my laptop lid and reopen it, the laptop is "on" but does not wake from suspend at all, and it is necessary to restart the computer every time. I've been browsing a lot of the threads on this problem, with no results. Importantly, I am using AMD graphics (Ryzen 7 Pro 6850U with Radeon graphics), and so all the solutions about messing with nouveau drivers are completely irrelevant to me. I have Gnome 42.5 and kernel 5.19.0-45-generic.

[I do not have a "Sleep Mode" option in my BIOS;](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368951/thinkpad-t14-doesnt-wake-up-from-suspend) seems like [newer ones don't have it](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/lnyrt6/comment/i0p6nlt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button). [I've turned off "security chip" (and secure boot) in the BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457070/ubuntu-22-04-not-waking-up-after-second-suspend), and have disabled Wayland. [I have not been able to successfully access the Lenovo advanced BIOS menu to switch from Modern Standby power to S3](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418046/556726), though I've tried to disable it via by Windows 10 dual boot.

If anyone knows how to get into the advanced BIOS menu or knows another solution besides "switch desktop environments", it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good problem description from your side. Helped me to fix my problem.

I confirmed that I tried all the ideas you mentioned. Then I came across a [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2008774).

I also have/had this problem. ThinkPad P14s 3rd gen (21J6) with AMD Ryzen 7 pro 6850u with Radeon Graphics. Ubuntu 22.04. Kernel was 5.19.0-46-generic.

Those solutions did not work:

- no "Sleep Mode" option in my BIOS
- did not manage to successfully access the Lenovo advanced BIOS menu to switch from Modern Standby power to S3 (the apparently secret advanced BIOS settings)
- turned off "security chip" and secure boot in the BIOS
- disabled Wayland

What did work was to switch to kernel 6.12.14-060214-generic on Ubuntu 22.04. Now the suspend/wakeup cycle works. Laptop seems cool/normal and quiet for now.

The bug report also mentions other ideas.

I do have the issue where "there is a short moment where the plain screen content is visible
after wake up, but the screen is locked almost immediately." However, I can live with that.

If you want to try to switch kernels, I can recommend [mainland](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline).

Comment: Interesting, I'll investigate. Have you experienced any issues using an "unsupported" kernel version, since 22.04 only seems to support up to 5.19? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Are you sure about your kernel version? Last version is 6.4.X

Comment: Yup, confirmed by `uname -r`. I just mean that kernels >=6 are not officially supported under Ubuntu 22.04, as mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Support_.28BEWARE:_there_is_none.29). I'm just wary of switching to a kernel that isn't production. Thanks.

Comment: Kernel 6.1.12 has some graphical issues, but did indeed fix the sleep/power issues. Thanks again!